# Google Fiber WAN PoE passthrough two ports of managed switch?

Tags: routing, pfsense, wide-area-network, power-over-ethernet, ont

I have a network configuration I would like to make happen, but I'm at a loss at what to call this odd setup, which makes searching quite difficult.

I want to substitute the Google Fiber Networking Box (a rather useless "router" for power users) with my own pfSense router, which there are plenty of [tutorials](https://homelab.nicktripp.com/2018/03/04/configuring-pfsense-for-google-fiber/) available for that but I would also like to simplify the wiring to the Fiber Jack (ONT) box by providing PoE to it, which is normally done with a standalone injector but I already have a 8-port managed PoE switch involved. So ideally, it would further consolidate the setup to transparently pass the WAN connection through two ports of the switch as *if* it was a dumb injector, while still using the other 6 ports for normal LAN switching. The one complication I can foresee here is the managed switch messing with the ISP-required VLAN and QoS settings required to get connectivity.

What would I need to configure in the switch to ensure its as transparent as possible for the WAN side? It's a Dell X1008P.

[image: Example layout of proposed network configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The one complication I can foresee here is the managed switch messing with the ISP-required VLAN and QoS settings required to get connectivity.

If required you'd need to match the tagged VLAN setting on the PoE switch. Use the same VLAN towards the pfSense, either tagged or untagged, matching the pfSense's config.

Create another VLAN for your LAN to separate its traffic and you're pretty much set. Of course, you need to set up routing and firewalling on the pfSense to enable Internet access. Whatever QoS settings are required should be created on the pfSense as well (or alternatively on the switch, may be harder though).